# In iOS how to add a line above the Number Pad, in Swift?

Tags: ios, user-interface, keyboard, swift3, numpad

By default if you set a `UITextField` keyboard type to `Number Pad` when it is displayed, it appears without a keyline above the top keys (iOS10). Is there an easy way to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few options, including adding a 1px UIView to the bottom of your layout (perhaps showing/hiding it based on the keyboard notifications), but by far the simplest solution is to add an empty toolbar as the `UITextField`'s accessory view:

```
myTextField.inputAccessoryView = UIToolbar()
```

Which resolves the issue:

[image]